# Exclude words from expressjs route path

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way to make it so this does not match `/api` and `/assets`?

```
router.use("/:group", groupRouter);
```

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
router.use("/:group(!(api|assets))", groupRouter);
```

Also, I tried using a regex here but node gave me an error, saying it expected a callback rather than a regex.

Note: apparently `.use` does not capture `group` either, but that isn't necessary in my case. I just need it to match everything except a few words.

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted? A comment would be appreciated so I can improve, clarify, and/or reword the question.

Comment: Still confused why this post got downvoted...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used nested middleware to solve this.

```
router.use("/:group", function(req, res, next) {
  var excludes = ["api", "assets"];
  if (excludes.indexOf(req.params.group) !== -1) return next();
  else {
    router.use("/"+req.params.group, groupRouter);
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
router.use("/:group((?!(api|assets)\w+))", groupRouter);
```